# Unable to update span with observableArray length in Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, observable

I am new to KO and I have a question I cannot get around.

I don't understand the theory behind observable in this particular part of my try out. I have a span that should always update it self with the value of an observableArray (self.links) which is filled by the user through a form.

Everytime I push to the array I thought it should update automatically the span but it does not and I do not understand why, and that is my main issue, not understanding the why.

I know that if instead of

```
<div class="panel-heading"><span data-bind="text: numberOfLinks">
```

I have...

```
<div class="panel-heading"><span data-bind="text: links().length">
```

the span will automatically update, but the question is, how do I actually put that links().length value into a variable so it can be used in other places (this will probably not happen but I am curious).

I have here the js so it is easier: http://jsfiddle.net/Kc4vL/2/

Comment: you need ko.computed. http://jsfiddle.net/Kc4vL/4/  Read here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use link().length to show number of links:-

```
<span data-bind="text: links().length"></span> available links</div>
```

Or you have to use computed to get observableArray's length. there is one more way without computed, you can update numberOfLinks every time when you add new link.

```
    self.addLink = function(){

        self.links.push(new Link(self.linkToAdd()));
        self.numberOfLinks(self.links().length);
    };
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kc4vL/5/)

Comment: My main stupidity was not realizing that to update the variable you had to do self.numberOfLinks(self.links().length); as instead of self.numberOfLinks = self.links().length; thank you so much for your availability :)